# jenkins parameter behaves differently from internally defined variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I set up my jenkins job to take in the parameter `payload` and set its value to `test\ntest`.

My jenkins script is the following:

```
def hardset = "test\ntest"

echo "param:"
def cleanParam = jenkinsParam.replaceAll("[\\n\\t ]","Yes");
echo cleanParam

echo "----------"

echo "hardset:"
def cleanHardset = hardset.replaceAll("[\\n\\t ]","Yes");
echo cleanHardset
```

The output is (cleaned up to remove jenkins pipeline echos):

```
test\ntest

param:
test\ntest

----------

hardset:
testYestest
```

Why? What's different between reading in a jenkins parameter and setting one in the script body?

In practice, I'm trying to replace troublesome `\n` coming in from a lambda payload, but this is throwing a wrench in my plans.

doing something like `def hardsetParam = jenkinsParam` to set it in the script body doesn't seem to work either, sadly.

In response to a comment - doing `echo jenkinsParam` gives me `test\ntest`. To my eyes, it's identical to hardset.

Comment: Can you print the value of jenkinsParam and show us what it prints exactly?

Comment: @Samit added at the bottom

Comment: You can try to do `echo hardset` and see if the behaviour is similar to what I have just answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `jenkinsParam` is holding the output after escaping the special characters.
You are assuming that `jenkinsParam = "test\ntest"` and however it looks like it stores it as `jenkinsParam = "test\\ntest"`

See how it behaves if I use echo it these two different cases:

(I have tested this in groovy shell)

**1st Case:**

```
jenkinsParam = "test\ntest"
print jenkinsParam
test
test
```

** 2nd Case:**

```
jenkinsParam = "test\\ntest"
print jenkinsParam
test\ntest
```

In order to replace the `payload` which is stored in the `jenkinsParam` (2nd case behaviour), you need to replace the complete `\\n` from the string. Check the example below:

```
output = jenkinsParam.replaceAll('\\\\n', 'yes')
print output
testyestest
```

Comment: oh interesting - I confirmed that you're right with hardset's behavior as well! In that case do you have any idea how I can actually replace `\n` with another character? Neither my original substitution nor, say, `\\n` seems to be working

Comment: updated the answer. try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: yep you're right - thanks!